# validação de multiplos selects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu verifico se todos os selects foram selecionados?

Primeiro eu verifico se ele é diferente de selecione, o usuário precisa marcar uma opção diferente de "selecione".

Depois preciso verificar se em todos os selects estao diferente de "selecione"

Enquanto não diferentes de "selecione" não posso enviar o form.

meu jQuery:

```
  $('#results-answers').children('select').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() != "Selecione"){
     $('#results-answer select').removeClass('flagError');
    }
    else{
     $('#results-answers select').addClass('flagError');
     return false;
    }
   });
```

Esse é o html com um dos selects (são 5 atualmente, mas pode variar dinamicamente a quantidade, pois vem de um ajax)

```
 <div class="" id="results-answers">
  <select class="form-control answers" id="1"> 
  <option>Selecione</option>
  <option value="true" data-question-code="1">Sim</option>
  <option value="false" data-question-code="1">Não</option>
  </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha sugestão é colocar um `value` vazio em cada primeiro `option`:

```
<option value="">Selecione</option>
```

Na função que vai validar você não precisa fazer laço `each`. Basta verificar os que estão vazios:

```
function validar(){
   var resps = $('#results-answers .answers');          // seleciona os selects pela classe
   var erros = resps.find('option:selected[value=""]'); // seleciona os selects com option vazio
   resps.removeClass('flagError');                      // remove a classe de todos
   erros.parent().addClass('flagError');                // adiciona a classe nos vazios

   if(erros.length) return false;                       // se houver um vazio retorna falso
   console.log("envia o formulário!");                  // envia o formulário
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
function validar(){
   var resps = $('#results-answers .answers');          // seleciona os selects pela classe
   var erros = resps.find('option:selected[value=""]'); // seleciona os selects com option vazio
   resps.removeClass('flagError');                      // remove a classe de todos
   erros.parent().addClass('flagError');                // adiciona a classe nos vazios
   
   if(erros.length) return false;                       // se houver um vazio retorna falso
   console.log("envia o formulário!");                  // envia o formulário
}
```

```css
.flagError{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" id="results-answers">
  <select class="form-control answers" id="1"> 
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="true" data-question-code="1">Sim</option>
  <option value="false" data-question-code="1">Não</option>
  </select>

  <select class="form-control answers" id="2"> 
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="true" data-question-code="2">Sim</option>
  <option value="false" data-question-code="2">Não</option>
  </select>

  <select class="form-control answers" id="3"> 
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="true" data-question-code="3">Sim</option>
  <option value="false" data-question-code="3">Não</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <button onclick="validar()">Validar</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use o selector `$('select option:selected[value=Selecione]')`  para saber se há algum select com essa opção "Selecione" selecionada:

```js
$( "#validar" ).click(function() {
  console.log($('select option:selected[value=Selecione]').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <select>
     <option value='Selecione'>Selecione</option>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
  </select>
 </p>
 <p>
  <select>
     <option value='Selecione'>Selecione</option>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
  </select>
 </p>
 <p>
  <select>
     <option value='Selecione'>Selecione</option>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
  </select>
 </p>
 
 <button id='validar'>Validar</button>
```